# Freezing SPL Token accounts Via JS SDK

Tags: metaplex, nft, staking, freeze-token-account, freeze

I am trying to build a 'web2'/'weak' NFT staking system where NFTs are frozen in holder's wallets.

Currently, the tokens do not have any freeze authority set. Does this mean they cant be frozen by me currently? If so, Is it possible for users to interact with a program to change this?

Is it possible for me to freeze NFTs with JS somehow?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

If the mint's `freeze_authority` is set to `None` then account freezing is permanently disabled.

Otherwise, you can use the `SetAuthority` instruction to change a Mint's `freeze_authority`

https://spl.solana.com/token#freezing-accounts

Answer (score 0):

If the NFT is indeed a master edition or a print using the metaplex standard you can use the example from my answer here

[How does one implement non-custodial NFT staking?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/how-does-one-implement-non-custodial-nft-staking)

Otherwise, if it is a fungible token with metadata, you can directly use the freeze_authority as mention by @C_Oggoo