# How does non-custodial NFT staking work?

Tags: anchor, nft, staking

In custodial NFT staking the holder transfers the NFT to a program-owned account to receive program-defined benefits. I've seen the same staking features implemented in a non-custodial manner and was wondering how this works.

How does a non-custodial NFT staking program work when the NFT remains in the holder's wallet and unlisted on a marketplace? I don't understand how a program can determine/prevent indirect unstaking by listing/selling/trading without being in possession of it.

Can someone explain on a high level what a relatively simple implementation of this would look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those non-custodial NFT staking solution must use the `freeze_delegated_account` instruction from the metaplex token metadata program.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/7c4ceb0100364901f2317f3421aab0aac400b647/token-metadata/program/src/processor.rs#L1552-L1606

It is quite simple, the transaction needs to `token::approve` the user "staking" program authority, then calling the `mpl_token_metadata::freeze_delegated_account` will:

- Check that the NFT token account delegate is signing and that delegate_amount is at least one.
- Perform a `token::freeze_account` using the feeze authority which is under the metaplex metadata program control.

As a result the NFT token account is frozen, the user cannot directly perform any action on it (transfer, revoke...) until he calls the same staking program to perform the opposite operation `thaw_delegated_account`

Comment: Also, check the Cardinal Github to see the staking contract they use: https://github.com/cardinal-labs